# Whether replacing the CPU of the NEXUS 5X would affect the OTA service?

Tags: ota-update, nexus-5x

Since my NEXUS 5X had encountered the famous boot looping issue, I sent it to the local phone repairing shop. As the result, they replaced my phone's CPU and the IMEI also became 0. So, whether this would affect me to receive Google's OTA service?